# JTable / JDBC won't work outside of Eclipse

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

This is frustrating me to no end.  I've written an app in Java that runs perfectly well in Eclipse.  How it should work is that I enter some search terms into a text field then, after pushing the "Search" button, the program accesses a remote mySQL DB using JDBC to search for the terms then a dialog with a JTable pops up and populates with the results of the search.

Like I've said, when running the program from within Eclipse it works beautifully.  But after I export into a JAR file and run it as a stand alone program, the JTable will no longer populate.  The dialog pops up as it should but it's empty.  I receive no errors or anything, just no results.

I can't figure out what's different between running it in Eclipse and stand alone.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: When you run your standalone JAR, do you include the jdbc driver in the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting that you should receive an exception error, but your code has an empty `catch` block that swallows it.

I'm also betting that your executable JAR doesn't have proper access to the JDBC driver JAR for MySQL, so you'll see a `ClassNotFoundException` when you try to get the `Connection`.

Overreliance on Eclipse is a very bad thing.  You need to know how to package and deploy an app without it.

Can't do more than guess based on what you've posted.

Comment: It didn't have the correct access to the driver.  Thanks for brainstorming it for me!